# GCC 4.8.4 Error on Ubuntu 14.04 VM: -std=c++11 flag isn't being detected

Tags: ubuntu, c++11, gcc, makefile, repast-hpc

I've looked everywhere online and can't seem to find a solution to this issue. I have tried -std=c++11, -std=c++0x, and -std=c++1y flags in the makefile and env file, all of which have no effect on the following errors:

```
'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
range based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
```

I am trying to run a C++ program built on top of RepastHPC, which is running on an Ubuntu 14.04 VirtualBox VM. Both the makefile for RepastHPC itself and the env file for the C++ code contain the flag. The env file is used in the makefile for the C++ code, so it isn't missing from there.

```
# Repast HPC 
# ENVIRONMENT DEFINITIONS

MPICXX=/home/repasthpc/repast_hpc-2.1.0/INSTALLATION/mpich-3.1.4/src/env/mpicxx
-std=c++11 -D USE_CPP11 -stdlib=libc++

BOOST_INCLUDE=-I/usr/local/include/
BOOST_LIB_DIR=-L/usr/local/lib/
BOOST_LIBS=-lboost_mpi-mt-s -lboost_serialization-mt-s -lboost_system-mt-s -lboost_filesystem-mt-s

REPAST_HPC_INCLUDE=-I/usr/local/include/
REPAST_HPC_LIB_DIR=-L/usr/local/lib/
REPAST_HPC_LIB=-lrepast_hpc-2.1

TISSUE_INCLUDE=-I/Users/repasthpc/Desktop/hpcmodel/angiogenesis_osteogenesis_simulator/src/

------------------------------------------------------------

# Repast HPC
# MANUAL BUILD MAKEFILE

# VARIABLES (Supply values for these; for definitions and examples, see INSTALL)
CXX=mpicxx      -std=c++11 -D USE_CPP11
CXXLD=mpicxx
BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include
BOOST_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/lib
BOOST_INFIX=-mt
NETCDF_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include
NETCDF_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/lib
CURL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include
CURL_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/lib
```

** This is not the end of the makefile, but it is the end of the relevant section **

Any thoughts? I am thoroughly confused.

Thanks!
Rachael

Comment: If `MPICXX=...` and `-std=c++11` are really on two different lines in the makefile then the `-std=c++11` line is **not** part of the `MPICC` assignment and will **not** be used during compilation.

Comment: I have tried it with them in the same line, but that also gives me an error whether it is separated by a space or a tab:   

g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’

Comment: I just removed that flag, which seems to fix that particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple issues with this Makefile:

**1)**`CXX=mpicxx`  **does not do what you are intending.**

The correct way to do this is

```
CXX=$(MPICXX)
```

This translates to:

```
CXX=/home/repasthpc/repast_hpc-2.1.0/INSTALLATION/mpich3.1.4/src/env/mpicxx
```

**2)** **Also notice that the `-std=c++11 -D USE_CPP11 -stdlib=libc++` part is not included in CXX above. This is because we need a '\' to tell Make that there is another line as well.**

So try this:

```
MPICXX=/home/repasthpc/repast_hpc-2.1.0/INSTALLATION/mpich-3.1.4/src/env/mpicxx \
-std=c++11 -D USE_CPP11 -stdlib=libc++

BOOST_INCLUDE=-I/usr/local/include/
BOOST_LIB_DIR=-L/usr/local/lib/
BOOST_LIBS=-lboost_mpi-mt-s -lboost_serialization-mt-s -lboost_system-mt-s -lboost_filesystem-mt-s

REPAST_HPC_INCLUDE=-I/usr/local/include/
REPAST_HPC_LIB_DIR=-L/usr/local/lib/
REPAST_HPC_LIB=-lrepast_hpc-2.1

TISSUE_INCLUDE=-I/Users/repasthpc/Desktop/hpcmodel/angiogenesis_osteogenesis_simulator/src/

------------------------------------------------------------

# Repast HPC
# MANUAL BUILD MAKEFILE

# VARIABLES (Supply values for these; for definitions and examples, see INSTALL)
CXX=$(MPICXX)      -std=c++11 -D USE_CPP11
CXXLD=$(MPICXX)
BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include
BOOST_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/lib
BOOST_INFIX=-mt
NETCDF_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include
NETCDF_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/lib
CURL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include
CURL_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Sorry, the first one actually produces a good deal of errors. I'm switching it back for the time being.

Implemented the second one, now getting the following errors: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_mpi-mt-s /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_serialization-mt-s /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-mt-s /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mt-s – 

Not sure where that's coming from, /usr/bin/ld doesn't seem to be anywhere in these files.

Comment: Turns out I had a "-s" at the end of the filename in the env file that was not in the actual filename. Everything works now. Thanks!